# how to load QGIS workspace in Qfield. There is no /android folder

Tags: qgis, qfield

I am trying to load a Workspace into Qfield on my S8 android phone. I have followed the steps on any website i have come across but I am unable to find or access the folder in which my layers and workspace have been placed. When trying to save the folder on my phones internal memory I have put in in the /android/data/ch.opengis.qfield/files/newworkspace but when i try to access this through qfield I cannot seem to get into the /android folder as it is not there on my device. I have pressed the upwards arrow as many times as possible and the first 4 options in my list are as follows

acct

cache

config

cpefs

I have also tried saving the workspace and layers on my sdcard as I can access this but when i get as far as the sdcard/ch.opengis.qfield/files I cannot see the folder in there in which I have created that is holding my workspace information.